# API call with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, openweathermap

I am trying to use Android studio to access a streaming/internet API. My API call works in Eclipse without using AsyncTask so I'm trying to use AsyncTask in Android Studio to call the API but I'm not sure why it's not working. The way I use the buffered reader and input stream are the same as the way I used them in eclipse when the call works. I also have permission to use internet in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Note: I took out my API key for obvious reasons.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG_DEBUG = MainActivity.class.getName();
public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
public static final String TAG_CURRENTTEMP = "currenttemp";
public static final String TAG_MAXTEMP = "maxtemp";
public static final String TAG_MINTEMP = "mintemp";

private EditText enteredzip;
private String zip;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enteredzip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    zip = enteredzip.getText().toString();

    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

}

class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

   protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

        String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=";
        String API_CALL = "&APPID=key";
        // Do some validation here
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        String bufferedOutput = "";
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(BASE_URL + zip + API_CALL)).openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();
            
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line + "\r\n");
            is.close();
            con.disconnect();
            bufferedOutput = buffer.toString();
            return bufferedOutput;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            try{
                is.close();
            }catch(Throwable T){}
            try{
                con.disconnect();
            }catch(Throwable T){}
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            //response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.error_et), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        //Log.i("INFO", response);
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String id = "";
        String currenttemp = "";
        String maxtemp = "";
        String mintemp = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            if (response.substring(i, i + 2).equals("id")) {
                id = response.substring(i + 4, i + 7);
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            if (response.substring(i, i + 4).equals("temp")) {
                currenttemp = response.substring(i + 6, i + 9);
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            if (response.substring(i, i + 8).equals("temp_min")) {
                mintemp = response.substring(i + 10, i + 13);
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            if (response.substring(i, i + 8).equals("temp_max")) {
                maxtemp = response.substring(i + 10, i + 13);
                break;
            }
        }

        launchMain2Activity(id, currenttemp, maxtemp, mintemp);
    }
}

private void launchMain2Activity(String id, String currenttemp, String maxtemp, String mintemp) {
    Intent Main2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

    Main2Activity.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
    Main2Activity.putExtra(TAG_CURRENTTEMP, currenttemp);
    Main2Activity.putExtra(TAG_MAXTEMP, maxtemp);
    Main2Activity.putExtra(TAG_MINTEMP, mintemp);


    startActivity(Main2Activity);
}
```

Comment: What does your log says?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")) ;
```

UTF-8 is a method for encoding Unicode characters using 8-bit sequences.